# WPF Path's Geometry Transform performance gets worse with LineGeometries' length increase

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm currently trying to create a little plot interactive editor, using WPF.
On maximized window the plot dragging with mouse is not responsive enough because of the plot grid.

I got a path for my plot grid lying inside a Canvas control (render transform just shifts it to the bottom of the canvas)

```
<Path Name="VisualGrid" RenderTransform="{StaticResource PlotTechnicalAdjust}" Style="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=GridStyle}" Panel.ZIndex="1"/>
```

Here is how grid is created; _curState has actual camera "viewport" metadata

```
  if (_curState.Changes.ScaleStepXChanged)
     {
        foreach (TextBlock item in _xLabels)
        {
           DeleteLabel(item);
        }
        _xLabels.Clear();
        double i = _curState.LeftEdgeLine;
        _gridGeom.Children[(int)GridGeomIndexes.VerticalLines] = new GeometryGroup { Transform = _verticalLinesShift};
        var verticalLines =(GeometryGroup)_gridGeom.Children[(int)GridGeomIndexes.VerticalLines];
        while (i <= _curState.RightEdgeLine * (1.001))
        {
           verticalLines.Children.Add(new LineGeometry(new Point(i * _plotParameters.PixelsPerOneX, 0),
                                                       new Point(i * _plotParameters.PixelsPerOneX,
                                                                 -_wnd.ContainerGeneral.Height)));
           _xLabels.Add(CreateLabel(i, Axis.X));
           i += _curState.CurrentScaleStepX;
        }
        _curState.Changes.ScaleStepXChanged = false;
     }
     if (_curState.Changes.ScaleStepYChanged)
     {
        foreach (TextBlock item in _yLabels)
        {
           DeleteLabel(item);
        }
        _yLabels.Clear();
        double i = _curState.BottomEdgeLine;
        _gridGeom.Children[(int)GridGeomIndexes.HorizontalLines] = new GeometryGroup { Transform = _horizontalLinesShift};
        var horizontalLines = (GeometryGroup)_gridGeom.Children[(int)GridGeomIndexes.HorizontalLines];
        while (i <= _curState.TopEdgeLine * (1.001))
        {
           horizontalLines.Children.Add(new LineGeometry(new Point(0, -i * _plotParameters.PixelsPerOneY),
                                                           new Point(_wnd.ContainerGeneral.Width,
                                                                    -i * _plotParameters.PixelsPerOneY)));
           _yLabels.Add(CreateLabel(i, Axis.Y));
           i += _curState.CurrentScaleStepY;
        }
        _curState.Changes.ScaleStepYChanged = false;
     }
```

Where Transforms are composition of TranslateTransform and ScaleTransform (for vertical lines I only use X components and only Y for horizontal lines).
After beeing created those GeometryGroups are only edited if a new line apears into camera or an existing line exits viewable space. Grid is only recreated when axis graduations have to be changed after zooming.

I have a dragging option implemented like this:

```
private Point _cursorOldPos = new Point();
private void OnDragPlotMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Handled)
      return;
   Point cursorNewPos = e.GetPosition(ContainerGeneral);
   _plotView.TranslateShiftX.X += cursorNewPos.X - _cursorOldPos.X;
   _plotView.TranslateShiftY.Y += cursorNewPos.Y - _cursorOldPos.Y;
   _cursorOldPos = cursorNewPos;
   e.Handled = true;
}
```

This works perfectly smooth with a small window (1200x400 units) for a large amount of points (like 100+).
But for a large window (fullscreen 1920x1080) it happens pretty jittery even without any data-point controls on canvas.
The strange moment is that lags don't appear when I order my GridGenerator to keep around 100+ lines for small window and drag performance suffers when I got less than 50 lines on maximezed. It makes me think that it might somehow depend not on a number of elements inside a geometry, but on their linear size.
I suppose I should mention that OnSizeChanged I adjust the ContainerGeneral canvas' height and width and simply re-create the grid.

Checked the number of lines stored in runtime to make sure I don't have any extras. Tried using Image with DrawingVisual instead of Path. Nothing helped.

Appearances for clearer understanding

[image]

[image]

Comment: http://imgur.com/leJQLPd - Weird moment. This crazy lines carnage works much smoother than a usuall grid in a maximized window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was all about stroke dashes and WPF's unhealthy desire to count them all while getting hit test bounds for DrawingContext.

The related topic is [Why does use of pens with dash patterns cause huge (!) performance degredation in WPF custom 2D drawing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/537950/why-does-use-of-pens-with-dash-patterns-cause-huge-performance-degredation-i)