# Slow performance using dashed lines on Canvas

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to create a grid using `Canvas` with horizontal and vertical lines. The problem is in very bad performance when I'm using dashed lines instead of solid. Is there any solution to solve this? I don't need the possibility to handle events of this dashed lines (maybe exists some 'lightweight' version of canvas object...).

If I add `StrokeDashArray` to the `Line` object the application is very slow...

```
        private void DrawGrid()
        {
            var brush = new SolidColorBrush((Color) ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#cccccc"));

            for (int i = 100; i < _areaSize; i += 100)
            {
                var hLine = new Line
                {
                    X1 = 0,
                    Y1 = i,
                    X2 = _areaSize,
                    Y2 = i,
                    Stroke = brush,
                    StrokeThickness = 1,
                    SnapsToDevicePixels = true,
                };

                var vLine = new Line
                {
                    X1 = i,
                    Y1 = 0,
                    X2 = i,
                    Y2 = _areaSize,
                    Stroke = brush,
                    StrokeThickness = 1,
                    SnapsToDevicePixels = true
                };

                //hLine.SetValue(RenderOptions.EdgeModeProperty, EdgeMode.Aliased);
                //vLine.SetValue(RenderOptions.EdgeModeProperty, EdgeMode.Aliased);

                Container.Children.Add(hLine);
                Container.Children.Add(vLine);
                Panel.SetZIndex(hLine, -1000);
                Panel.SetZIndex(vLine, -1000);
            }
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean with "very bad performance". You create the lines once, what happens then? How large is _areaSize? How does your potential StrokeDashArray look like?

Comment: When I'm using solid lines I can drag the canvas without any freeze, but when lines are dashed the application starts very slow and there are freezes when I'm dragging canvas.

_areaSize = 100 000 (I wrapped the Canvas in ScrollViewer)

Comment: did you try the performance profiler? you could profile the performance with dash and without dash and compare the two profiles, maybe you will find a difference. 
maybe the dashed line takes more processing than the solid line

Comment: From my tests i think the problem is adding the children to the collection. Theres a lot of events on rendering the children. If the content cannot be interacted with and is essentially static maybe consider using a Pen to draw on the canvas instead. http://csharphelper.com/blog/2015/04/render-dashed-lines-in-a-wpf-program-using-c/

Comment: Also, the Pen can then be frozen (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.pen(v=vs.110).aspx) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/537950/why-does-use-of-pens-with-dash-patterns-cause-huge-performance-degredation-i

Comment: Here is more information that may shed light on what you're trying to do https://stackoverflow.com/a/9996707/99804